# How ignore specific lines of file using Regex and diff utility ("-I regex" option)?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ubuntu, diff

I am writing automation tests to compare HTML files. For comparation I use [`diff` linux utility](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/diff.1.html)

So, First HTML file  `1.html`

```html
<!-- just example -->
<html>
  <div id="userdata_hidden">bla bla bla</div>
  <div id="something else" >bla bla bla</div>
  <div id="waiver_id"      >bla bla bla</div>
<html>
```

Second HTML file `2.html`

```html
<!-- just example -->
<html>
  <div id="userdata_hidden">bla bla bla DIFFERENCE </div>
  <div id="something else" >bla bla bla</div>
  <div id="waiver_id"      >bla bla bla DIFFERENCE </div>
<html>
```

Сommand to compare files:

```
diff -biw 1.html 2.html
```

Result:

```
3c3
<   <div id="userdata_hidden">bla bla bla</div>
---
>   <div id="userdata_hidden">bla bla bla DIFFERENCE </div>
5c5
<   <div id="waiver_id"      >bla bla bla</div>
---
>   <div id="waiver_id"      >bla bla bla DIFFERENCE </div>
```

Comaration works fine, but I need to ignore difference of lines which include special words - `waiver_id` and `userdata_hidden`.

`diff` command have [`-I` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Specified-Lines.html#Specified-Lines) for ignoring lines by number or regex match:

> To ignore insertions and deletions of lines that match a grep-style
>   regular expression, use the --ignore-matching-lines=regexp (-I regexp)
>   option. You should escape regular expressions that contain shell
>   metacharacters to prevent the shell from expanding them. For example,
>   ‘diff -I '^[[:digit:]]'’ ignores all changes to lines beginning with a
>   digit.
>
> However, -I only ignores the insertion or deletion of lines that
>   contain the regular expression if every changed line in the hunk—every
>   insertion and every deletion—matches the regular expression. In other
>   words, for each nonignorable change, diff prints the complete set of
>   changes in its vicinity, including the ignorable ones.
>
> You can specify more than one regular expression for lines to ignore
>   by using more than one -I option. diff tries to match each line
>   against each regular expression.

So, I can use regex to ignore comaration of lines with `waiver_id` or `userdata_hidden`. If files have no differences `diff` returns nothing (empty string) to console.

Question:

1. How to write regex, which exclude strings that contain words waiver_id or userdata_hidden?
2. How correct `diff` command should look with `-I` option and regex?

P.S. Unfortunately, this variant not working:

```
diff -biw -I '^(?!.*(?:userdata_hidden|waiver_id))' 1.html 2.html
```

Comment: That really looks like a "Do my homework" type of question...

Comment: @JérémieAstori Astori, no I am writing automation tests with ruby. Trying to compare two HTML and pdf files with bash `diff` command

Comment: @JérémieAstori, diff command has `-I /regex/` option which gives a possibility to ignore comaration of lines which match some regexp

Comment: That's what it looks like when someone just asks a solution without even posting experiments :-) Please include what you have tried so far and their results, rather than just an answer from scratch.

Comment: That being said, if performance is not of the essence and you have just 2 needles (your 2 words), you could just use something along the lines of `!str.match('waiver_id') && !str.match('userdata_hidden')` and avoid yourself the pain of the regexes...

Comment: Comming back a couple of days later, now that's a real question :) Don't forget to select the right answer when you are done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to check that string does not contain words `waiver_id` and `userdata_hidden`.

```
^(?!.*\bwaiver_id\b)(?!.*\buserdata_hidden\b)
```

If you don't want any one string to be presented.

```
^(?!.*\b(?:userdata_hidden|waiver_id)\b)
```

[RUbular](http://www.rubular.com/r/0FaAMaHHHH)

Comment: string should not contain any of this words (or instead of and)

Comment: it should looks like `/^(?!.*\bwaiver_id\b)|(?!.*\buserdata_hidden\b)$/`, isn't it?

Comment: @bmalets change and to or

Comment: @bmalets: No. Your regex makes no sense at all, since `^` belong to the first branch, and `$` belongs to the second branch. You probably mean `/^((?!.*\bwaiver_id\b)|(?!.*\buserdata_hidden\b))/`, but it is wrong, since this means either (no waiver_id) or (no userdata_hidden), which means allows them as long as both don't appear at the same time.

Comment: @cremno special words may be in any part of string/line

Comment: I populated question description with more details.